# Error in reading all files present in a folder

Tags: python

I have this directory containing 50 files and I want to read each file and store all text of that file in a index of my list so after some research I wrote the following code but it gives me error at this line :

```
filedata[i]=filee.read()

IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Here is the code:

```
import os

filedata = list()

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('Doc50'):
    print(filenames[4])

i=1

for file in filenames:
    fpath = os.getcwd()
    fpath = os.path.join(fpath, str(dirpath))
    fpath = os.path.join(fpath, str(filenames[i]))
    filee = open(fpath,mode='r')
    print("value of i: " + str(i))
    filedata[i]=filee.read()
    filee.close()
    i=i+1

print(filedata)
```

I am new in python so pardon me if you find this code lengthy and if it could be done in more optimized way please let me know.

Comment: `filedata` is an empty list, you can't index it. You probably wanted to use `append` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lists are not like arrays in other languages; they do not have a predetermined size and are not sparse.

Hence, assigning to a specific index when the list has length `0` throws an `IndexError` because you are saying "re-assign the `i`-th element to be this" when there is no `i`-th element".

Instead, you want to append elements to the end of the list.

Also, your code has many other confusing parts to it, so rather than trying to muddle through it, the following code will simply produce a list of strings of the contents of each file in the current working directory (note that this will include the Python script itself, so you may want to filter out the name of the script).

```
import os

file_data = []
files_in_cwd = os.listdir()
for file_name in files_in_cwd:
    with open(file_name) as file_handler:
        file_data.append(file_handler.read())

print(file_data)
```

---

Note that you should always use a `with` statement when opening files and that `mode='r'` is the default, also the usual way of creating an empty list is with `[]`.

Comment: @Hammad97 No problem

Answer (score 0):

> *A mistake i found:* Arrays and lists start with an index of 0.
>   IndexError appears when trying to get a list[2] of a list only containing 2 items.
>   as mentioned lists start at 0 so list[2] means list item number 3.

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('Doc50'):
    print(filenames[4])

i=1
```

replace `i=1` with `i=0`

Comment: because the second half contradicts the first half: you cannot assign to indexes in a list - they are not some sort of sparse array so why then does Stanley talk about the start index being `0` ?

Comment: My problem was that i was not using append as corrected by Joe and Rogash up there ... Still thanks for your reply

Comment: I see, thank you for getting back to me with the correct answer, much appreaciated!